# How to fulfill generic constraint for consuming type?

Tags: swift, generics

I have a type with a generic type. I'm trying to make it a property on another type but don't know how to make the typealias fulfill the generic type.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
protocol StoreType: AnyObject {
    associatedtype State: StateType
    func send(_ action: State.Action)
}

struct MainPresenter {
    typealias Store = StoreType where Store.State == MainState

    private let store: Store

    init(store: Store) {
        self.store = store
    }
}
```

This gives me a compile error of `'where' clause cannot be attached to a non-generic declaration`. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: You are not giving enough info. What is MainState? Provide the declarations of  _all_ types mentioned anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MainPresenter` is generic over `Store`. `Store` needs to be in the type definition.

You can prefix it with the name of your module so you don't need to use some `Type` suffix. (`Type` is the old convention. People [use `Protocol` now](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/iteratorprotocol) when it's necessary because shadowing isn't possible.)

```swift
protocol Store: AnyObject {
  associatedtype State: Module.State
  func send(_ action: State.Action)
}

struct MainPresenter<Store: Module.Store> where Store.State == MainState {
  private let store: Store

  init(store: Store) {
    self.store = store
  }
}
```